# Error in javascript / ajax / json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, syntax

im gettin an error with this code. the error is : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"
THIS IS MY FUNCTION

```
function buscarMaterias()
{
  var primeraVez = true;
  var desarolloMaterias;
  var infraMaterias;
  var value = sel.value;
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log(1+1);
    if(primeraVez)
  {
    console.log(1+2);
    ajax.open('GET', 'desarrollo.json');
    ajax.send();
    desarolloMaterias = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
    ajax.open('GET', 'infraestructura.json');
    ajax.send(); 
    infraMaterias = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
    primeraVez = false;
  }
  console.log(1+3);
  switch(value)
  {
  case "1":
    dibujarMaterias(desarolloMaterias);
    break;
  case "2":
    dibujarMaterias(infraMaterias); 
    break;
    default:
    dibujarMaterias([{"id":0,"descripcion":"ELIGE UNA CARRERA"}]);
  }

}
```

i know the error is from a missing {,;] etc, but i just cant get where is a missing character

Comment: fyi `XMLHttpRequest` is async - so you have to handle `onload`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the function in terms of closing brackets/braces. However `sel` isn't defined in the `var value` variable

Comment: Q: Have you considered the actual start brace is *OUTSIDE* of the snippet you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You may have more errors, but this is one's for sure:

In this line:

```
var value = sel.value;
```

because `sel` is not defined.

I used the javascript console and got that error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sel is not defined(…)
```

Use the javascript console for the browser you are using. I'm using [Chrome's](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), but FF and IE have the same thing.